# How to add a custom field to the Payload generated by AddMutationConventions()?

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am using `AddMutationConventions()` to save me from writing boilerplate code. However I [want to add a field `query: Query` to each Payload](https://graphql-rules.com/rules/mutation-payload-query). Is that possible in combination with `AddMutationConventions()` or do I have to write my own Payload by hand in that case?

Comment: This should be what you‘re looking for: https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/relay/#query-field-in-mutation-payloads

Comment: awesome, please post as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you can automatically add the query field to all mutation payloads with this configuration option:

```cs
services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryFieldToMutationPayloads();
```

[Reference](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/relay#query-field-in-mutation-payloads)